# Тачпад, ускорение в 2 раза, физика Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал управление персонажем на таче и по на клавиатуре. На тачксрине иногда, при очередной тапе, скорость персонажа резко( в 2 раза примерно) возрастает. Следующим тапом успешно всё выключается. Абсолютно случайно, пробовал 2 раза подряд тапать и удерживать - воспроизвести не удалось.

```
public Vector2 rightForce = new Vector2(300, 0);
public Vector2 leftForce = new Vector2(-300, 0);

void Update()
{

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)//код для тачскрина
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(leftForce);
        }
        else if (touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(rightForce);
        }
    }

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) //код для клавиатуры. 
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(leftForce);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(rightForce);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Поменял Update на FixedUpdate и все заработало.